# Как правильно написать условие с выбором option в select?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой код

```
<select>
  <option>Пункт 1</option>
  <option>Пункт 2</option>
</select>
```

Как написать условие, если выбран Пункт 2, то выполнять блок кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала снабдите элементы `<option>` атрибутом `value`. После чего добавьте обработчик события изменения селекта.

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
  <option value="2">Пункт 2</option>
</select>
```

на jQuery остальная часть будет выглядеть в виде:

```
$("#sel").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 2){
       //выполняем код при выборе "Пункт 2"
       alert("Выбран Пункт 2");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого html можно использовать и просто чистый Javascript. Если выбран второй option, то его порядковый номер из всех option'ов будет 1 (отсчёт идёт с 0) и выполняем код из блока условия.

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
  <option value="2">Пункт 2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
if (document.getElementById("sel").options.selectedIndex == 1) {
  //execute code
}
</script>
```